# mobile - how to create a "virtual number lock" with JS or pure CSS

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I'm experienced with web development, but I'm trying to learn some mobile and I'm not entirely sure I understand how to work with touch events. I looked at some guides ([for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)), but I'm not sure how to apply it in my case.

Consider this (ignore the quality of the code, I just doodled this quickly to explain my question):

```js
var span = $("span"),
    btns = $("button");
    
btns.on("click", function() {
     var $this  = $(this), 
         action = $this.data("action"),
         curVal = parseInt( span.text() );
     
     btns.prop("disabled", false);
     
     if (action == "less") {
        span.text(curVal-1);
        if (curVal == 2)
          $("#less").prop("disabled", true); 
     } else {
        span.text(curVal+1);
        if (curVal == 8)
          $("#more").prop("disabled", true);
     }
});
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }

button {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="less" data-action="less" disabled="disabled">&lt;</button>
<span>1</span>
<button id="more" data-action="more">&gt;</button>
```

I want to do that, but instead of buttons, I want it to respond to touch movement. i.e., when you slide your fingers right it would react like clicking on the right button and vice-versa. ideally, you would be able to slide back and the number would snap to your finger (sort of like a virtual number lock, like below, though horizontal)

[image]

I can measure the movement with `touchmove` and try to sync it visually but that seems like it would take ages and be a bugstrosity. Is there a better\simpler way? (related: is there a way to do this with pure CSS?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many touch events you want to support, I would look for an open source js library to handle this

One good example is
[HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/)